How to create alias for kubeconfig in Kubernetes
I'm on the very first steps on Kubernetes, and have a question if there any way to create context based on my kubeconfig file and then re-use by using
kubectl --context mycontext ?

It's a bit annoying to have in every command I execute with kubectl something like: 
kubectl -kubeconfig=~/.kube/<clustername>-kubeconfig.yaml

Or maybe there is some more advanced ways on how to handle authorization more easily? 
Any help is much appreciated!

You don't have to use the -kubeconfig flag every time you run a kubectl command - see https://devopscube.com/kubernetes-kubeconfig-file/

Hi @RuiJarimba . Can you post your comment, I'll mark it as resolved. Huge thanks

Also if you have multiple contexts in kubernetes, you can change them easily with this tool. https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx

There is also a $KUBECONFIG environment variable.  I personally have found a separate config file per environment (as in your second command) plus the environment-variable setting a little safer than having a single file with multiple contexts.
